# multi tab menu in a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a tab-menu and trying to use this tab-menu 2 times or more in a page.
But the tab-menu is not working well when multi use.

what do I need to fix the jquery ?

please help...

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
      var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

      $(this).addClass('current');
      $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
     })

    })
```

```css
      ul.tabs li{ padding:3px; display:inline-block } 
      ul.tabs li.current{ background: #ededed; color: #222; } 
      .tab-content{ display: none;    } 
      .tab-content.current{ display: inherit; }
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">

     <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li> 
     </ul>
     <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> 1111 </div>
     <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"> 2222</div> 
      
      <br><br>
      
      <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-3">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Two</li> 
     </ul>

     <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content current">33</div>
     <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">4</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: What is it about your provided code that isn't working correctly? What are your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using it is supposed to be one tab only because the code you shared **hide all other tabs on the page when one tab is selected**.

There is one way to solve it by recognizing the parent before showing or hiding tab content:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');

    $(parent).find('li').removeClass('current');
    $(parent).find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(parent).find("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  })
})
```

```css
ul.tabs li {
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
} 

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li> 
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> 1111 </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"> 2222</div> 
  </div>
  <br><br>

  <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-3">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Two</li> 
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content current">33</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">4</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

## Explanation

I added a `div` wrapper on each tab section. This div will be the guide for the code to act.

Once you click in a tab:

- it locates the closest parent that is a `div` and uses it as starting point
- it uses the show/hide logic only inside this div, not affecting other tabs on the page